How are we to understand the voice in Revelation 19:5?

And from the throne came a voice saying, “Praise our God,
all you his servants,
you who fear him,
small and great.” (Revelation 19:5 ESV)

It would seem like the voice from the throne is from the one sitting on the throne. Is that how are we to understand the voice?

The one sitting on the throne is God. It will be weird the voice begins with "Praise our God".

+1 I agree with @VincentWong. Perhaps from the general area of the throne? Open to be convinced otherwise.

Christ sits on the throne with his Father, telling all to praise his God, the Father.

@OneGodOneLord As in my other comment, if that were the case, I would expect the passage to be more specific in stating that. There is no specific identification of who spoke or of Christ or even the Father. I do not disagree Christ tells us to praise God. I don't see that in this particular passage.

Answer
The voice in Revelation 19:5 comes from one of the four living creatures.
Explanation
We read in Revelation 4:5:

“And out of the throne come forth lightnings and thunders and voices”.

I think this is a constant and important feature of God’s power shown in the Scripture.
For example, when God came down on Mount Sinai to thunder out the Ten Commandments, we read again:

“And on the third day, it being morning, it happened: There were
thunders and lightnings, and a heavy cloud on the mountain, and the
sound of a ram's horn, very strong! And all the people in the camp
trembled” (Exo 19:16).

God showed a little of His power:

“And all the people saw the thunders, and the lightnings, and the
sound of the ram's horn, and the smoking mountain. And the people
looked, and they trembled, and they stood from a distance” (Exo
20:18).

How does this work?
We may not know exactly. But the Scripture, nevertheless, explains:

“He makes His angels spirits, His ministers a flaming fire” (Psalms
104:4).

We see one sample in Ezekiel chapter 1:

“As for the likeness of the living creatures, their appearance was
like coals of fire, burning like the appearance of torches; it flashed
up and down among the living creatures (the same 4 living
creatures we see in Revelation); and there was brightness to the
fire, and out of the fire went forth lightning. And the living
creatures ran and returned as the appearance of a flash of lightning”
(Eze 1:13-14).

It sounds like some sci-fi movie!
Whose Voice
Whose voice do we hear in Revelation 19:5?
We read earlier in Revelation 5:6:

“And in the midst of the throne and around the throne were
four living creatures, full of eyes before and behind”.

The innermost circle is comprised of the four living creatures. They are “in the midst of the throne” and around the throne.
They are the ones who lead the worship service in heaven before God.

“And they had no rest day and night, saying, "Holy, holy, holy,
Lord God Almighty," the One who was, and is, and is coming!” (Rev
4:8).

In short, they lead the worship of God in heaven constantly (verses 9-10).
Conclusion
So, the voice came from one of the four living creatures who is “in the midst” of the throne of God, serving:

“and the four living creatures fell down and worshiped God sitting
on the throne, saying, Amen! Hallelujah! And a voice (from one
of them in the midst of the throne) came out from the throne, saying,
Praise our God, all His slaves, and the ones fearing Him, the small
and the great” (Rev 19:4-5).


+1.  Good answer.

Interesting, however, prior to this when one of the living creatures spoke it was stated directly. Also, since John says the four living creatures had fallen down, they would not be in the midst of the throne. The throne would be in the midst of the living creatures and elders.

Thank you, Dottard. I appreciate it.

@RevelationLad - I see angels everywhere in the presence of God. For example, Rev 16:5 says, “And I heard the angel of the waters saying….” Then verse 7 states, “And I heard another (angel) out of the altar saying…..”. You see, an angel in the midst of the altar! Now the Scripture says, as I pointed out in my answer, one living creature is “in the midst” of the throne. So, when they fall down to worship, one of them will be falling down “in the midst” of the throne.

Now, it is obvious that all the voice announcements in Revelation generally and in chapter 19 specifically, are talking about God and the Lamb. So, obviously these voices cannot be from God the Father or the Lamb. The only possibility then is the living creature in the midst of the throne. Now I know everyone will not agree to this, as the 2 down votes I got will prove.

Prior to verse 5, there were other voices heard. Many people in heaven said "Alleluia...", praising God, "our God" (vs. 1). Then came the voices of 24 elders, and four living creatures agreeing with that, as they fell down before God who sat on the throne, saying "Amen, Alleluia" (vs. 4).
Now comes the verse in question. Note how the voice is heard to "come out of the throne"? (vs. 5) This is a culminating witness issuing from the throne of God itself. Here is one explanation about that:

"A voice out of the throne might seem to indicate the deity himself.
Two things against this interpretation: First, were this the voice of
the Almighty, one would expect the wording 'A voice from the throne'
at least; or more appropriately 'the voice from the throne'; and
at most, "the voice of God from the throne": but none of these
things is said, implying that this is not the voice of God himself.
Second, were this the voice of God, it is impossible that the words of
the text 'praise our God' should be included. Just as God sware by
himself because he could sware by no greater, Hebrews 6:13, so he
cannot subjugate himself to his own name, as though that name were
greater than his own divine being: then he cannot say 'our God'. And
if not, this is not his voice.
Then whose voice is it? In such a figurative setting the answer
presents no difficulty. Since the voice came out of the throne,
symbolically it is to be regarded as if the very throne of God had
spoken: such a voice suggests the embodiment of all that the throne
implies from eternity to eternity. And what higher authority can exist
in a figure than that, save he who is enthroned over all? But seeing
as this is an exhortation to all who serve God, the seat of absolute
authority itself not being excluded in a figure, then what greater
common injunction lies upon all who serve him, whether significant or
insignificant; and everyone who fears him, whether great or small, to
praise or God?
And can the throne be said, in a figure, to speak with a voice? Then
how much more should all creation answer to it, as it is written 'Let
the heavens rejoice, and let the earth be glad; let the sea roar, and
the fulness thereof. Let the field be joyful, and all that is therein:
then shall all the trees of the wood rejoice', Psalm 96:11,12.... if
[God's servants] should hold their peace, the stones would immediately
cry out, Luke 19:40." The Revelation of Jesus Christ, John Metcalfe,
pp.505-6, http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us/htm
published 1998

This gives the answer that the throne of God itself, symbolically, 'speaks' the command.

What if it was Christ telling us to praise God?

@OneGodOneLord  Christ does tell us to praise God as do angelic messengers in the book of Revelation. In this verse we are not told who speaks; it is the authority of the throne of God that attention is directed to. When a command is issued with the authority of King Charles III, I am not concerned to know which person relays the command. As long as it issues from the throne, it is to be obeyed. The throne is the symbol of supreme authority in Rev. 19:5, that of he who sits on the throne, and the Lamb at the centre of the throne, which is surrounded by the 7-fold Spirit. Supreme authority.

@OneGodOneLord If it was Christ giving us instruction to do something, I would expect John to make that specific. Revelation 19 seems to describe creation's response to an accomplished act. not a general instruction to praise God for who He is.
